# Android: imageview touch and released

Tags: android, imageview, release

How to check if an ImageView was released?

This method is called when I touch the imageview.

```
myImageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
     return true;
   }
});
```

Is there any algorithm or method to "listen" if an imageview was released? (Pressing with a finger an ImageView, than releasing it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can detect the release action as below

```
myImageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
      if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
          // image released
      }
      return true;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

OnTouchListener touchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

                    //=====Write down your Finger Pressed code here

                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

                    //=====Write down you code Finger Released code here

                    return true;            
                }   

            return false;

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a way of how to detect when we touch([ACTION_DOWN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN)) and release ([ACTION_UP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP)) an ImageView using [**OnTouchListener**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) :

```
myImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                     //*TOUCH
                }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {                   
                    //*RELEASE
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```